# How to stop pandas from auto-converting symbols

Tags: python, pandas

I want to export a pandas dataframe to a latex table `.to_latex()`. One of my series I wish to export is the alpha symbol `\alpha`. However, pandas auto-converts this into a telephone symbol `(^Glpha)`

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'$\alpha$':[1]})
my_df
     ℎ 
0   1
```

Is there a way I can prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First [`\a` is an escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) so you need to use a raw string to avoid this being escaped by putting `r` before the string like

```
r'$\alpha$'
```

Secondly, `to_latex` will escape latex special characters in column names by default. Use

```
my_df.to_latex(escape=False)
```

to prevent this. So in summary the following should work

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={r'$\alpha$':[1]})
my_df.to_latex(escape=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'r' in fron to the string resolves the problem:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={r'$\alpha$':[1]})
my_df

      
0   1
```